# How to add additional data to Vega lite tooltip?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I'm trying to add an additional value (in this case z) to the tooltip. How can I achieve this with the following schema I have so far? I know it should be along the lines of adding additional objects to the tooltip array (one for last month and one for this month), but I'm unsure on how to map the values correctly. I can't seem to figure it out from the documentations and not seeing any examples of this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTfKj.png)

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "width": "container",
    "height": 300,
    "data": {
        "name": "table",
        "values": [
            {
                "x": "Sun - 1",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 1",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 1",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 1",
                "y": 0.7,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 1",
                "y": 0.23,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 1",
                "y": 0.45,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 1",
                "y": 0.21,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 1",
                "y": 0.11,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 1",
                "y": 0.79,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 1",
                "y": 0.35,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 1",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 1",
                "y": 0.28,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 1",
                "y": 0,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 1",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 2",
                "y": 0,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 2",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 2",
                "y": 0.21,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 2",
                "y": 0.11,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 2",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 2",
                "y": 0.7,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 2",
                "y": 0.1,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 2",
                "y": 0.5,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 2",
                "y": 0.58,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 2",
                "y": 0.2,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 2",
                "y": 0.23,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 2",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 2",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 2",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 3",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 3",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 3",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 3",
                "y": 0.21,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 3",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 3",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 3",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 3",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 3",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 4",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 4",
                "y": 0.23,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 4",
                "y": 0.21,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 4",
                "y": 0.79,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 4",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 4",
                "y": 0.82,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 4",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 4",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 5",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sun - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 5",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Mon - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 5",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Tue - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 5",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Wed - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 5",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Thu - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 5",
                "y": 0.18,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Fri - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "z": "03/01/23",
                "y": -0.01
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 5",
                "y": -0.01,
                "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                "z": "01/01/23"
            },
            {
                "x": "Sat - 5",
                "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                "y": -0.01
            }
        ]
    },
    "encoding": {
        "x": {
            "field": "x",
            "axis": {
                "labelAngle": 270
            },
            "title": "",
            "sort": null
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5
        }
    },
    "layer": [
        {
            "encoding": {
                "color": {
                    "field": "c",
                    "type": "nominal",
                    "title": "",
                    "scale": {
                        "range": [
                            "#CC3EBE",
                            "#5E5782"
                        ]
                    },
                    "legend": {
                        "orient": "top-left"
                    },
                    "sort": {
                        "field": "x",
                        "order": "ascending"
                    }
                },
                "y": {
                    "field": "y",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "title": "",
                    "scale": {
                        "domain": [
                            0,
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    "axis": {
                        "format": ".0~%",
                        "values": [
                            0,
                            0.25,
                            0.5,
                            0.75,
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    "stack": null
                },
                "xOffset": {
                    "field": "c"
                }
            },
            "layer": [
                {
                    "mark": {
                        "type": "bar",
                        "width": {
                            "band": 1
                        },
                        "align": "center"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "transform": [
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "param": "hover",
                                "empty": false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "mark": {
                        "type": "bar",
                        "width": {
                            "band": 1
                        },
                        "align": "center"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "transform": [
                {
                    "calculate": "datum.y >= 0 ? datum.y : -1",
                    "as": "y"
                },
                {
                    "pivot": "c",
                    "value": "y",
                    "groupby": [
                        "x"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "mark": "rule",
            "encoding": {
                "opacity": {
                    "condition": {
                        "value": 0.3,
                        "param": "hover",
                        "empty": false
                    },
                    "value": 0
                },
                "tooltip": [
                    {
                        "field": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
                        "type": "nominal",
                        
                        "title": "This Month"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
                        "type": "nominal",
                        
                        "title": "Last Month"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "params": [
                {
                    "name": "hover",
                    "select": {
                        "type": "point",
                        "fields": [
                            "x"
                        ],
                        "nearest": true,
                        "on": "mouseover",
                        "clear": "mouseout"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Link to the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLGgDMABltK1SPWlCykCOFr1NBXpcRIggxwEGgA2qAAHloAygyyAAT8iQCMpgCeaPy2lLapSlBaACowNBCJALK6MIkAFLYATASNAGwt1smJttYEtgDsHQCUpgBeWvl9qR0gAL4K0XEJXelKWag5eQXaWgAySBCYVTX1k5ONnSlNfQAsw2MTvefWcwsgMejVSSmrIOu5qQAHIUSmUKl96Kdmm0Ol0en1BhcRkpxugztMLq9Fp85CtMmhcv0Qeh9odjrJIQ1ps84c1bHckQ80U8MS95tiQMUQni1gTKBdiZyweTKdcYRc4U9EdZkSBUSB0TN2e8StyfvjULkbmJBaSjhDalSprCrnSGTKmQqWUq3h8QAB1OBqHl-PmNbZFdClcoiw1i9oSq5S+4oibU1lYlXoR3O9W8zWUVIevYHfUnI00023ENyx7GzHKu2lBgu-6UfoATkF3vB6f9Ju6wcZobR4ZtHOLpb51h1OxJqd9pzbge6Zpz8vhz0jdoAYkYaF2E4DGtXhQaoS0A5dGwjx2H82zbVo5wu466E41gX2QHrBxnWbTs83c8yD9O4s5Fw5rzW7-WR5O0qyhOw6HhysSfme6ybPkuoDuu94Ntc9J7q+U6Fks3yJI0Grfp6Qo+gh-7boBqEKqB77oPEWE4fGMHJv2ZJEaBj4oc+E7WgWR44jRuH8gxBG1hSfrQlukq7ux+7odxIBfF0tHngCAm3sxB6seawF5tJHZqthfFAquhF1qJSFNhaLbkW+GFerpCllkS14qXWLFZmx5kvlaVkyTG8n6YZQmiiZAFmZprZeRyPkpHZfK9vhTnCUOamuRplqThG1lCiWUV8WIV74b+RFBSRIWpRRGWdtl8a5Cujnwc5SWjk+7kceFUYgCevlVfy1j+X+RXiQMZGKlxHIdZV570XBTH1ZmjVuaFnnaW1EFHON0G5LBP5rsZm6mRJzVSelMkrZ1E0bcpdUJYhAFjpJaFHeBywpC8dHnb1hW7cF+0LcNYHLU9iQvWdWxTWmV2-epQ2cX9dpyc9fHLu9O3isV32la1sO4vDr0g7V03gy5c0pRZaXtm1XJwF0QNlojW1GeD-VBmjJNlTJFNUxqk142DoqE8hxMeaTI1tZFgMIzV+XbQzn2o4Nd2WUtdqi9T2Rvdzf587dB33WTRaMBzXXukj0sowNQHo4roJZWLoMaw1-NQ2+OP5BlY024piZ5aC9OBTLZtDazo3zgb6uqbNDvy0LKsbOdGUndjwObZLPsiX7TNy9rCsPctkHu3Fl28-bWs-dDnOx8dAM3GXuPJwFqem+n5ssxjmFdFXtthw+yWO1OzupBlcOJO3HsCnTdcbg3O4Zz9gdtYPw-5-jhfh8XqWl335W6cPZZG2PfVp1PTeC7PRZb6Yi8836mtNSXTuJ-33lOm3fGVsbvuT6Rkcn1oosLymS9XyLjfNed91pbHKvrFI28+S01rvvD+JVm6Wy9JAoe59-6X0SivYBJN1731dsHKB4s371zEo3AOLd0Buz-oxTB10SKr1waA1W4Djq52gTHGu3tx4NEZofChyCQDxzQR3GaXciY9wjBvCuWExDVyTtw+BZD+Ff0oUIgGcjREEyAfNEBvd8EyUHpoj2Bk94fQQczY+aijHoNoXbbBuimH6LAS7NmuljFllMXA8xyjP6Z1+pRTk7jbE3gLoAhxAsWrOJYa4iKT8UgeL5F4xRPi9rTwttnJW8TEjGIvvY8REd-F4JcQ-DsqDEkJmSSglOE9fGIKsYIiqOSQnxWXgUxhgtikxNKW1N2FSARe2qTw4i-tVGCL6S0sJWD2k4M6cwzhsSc6rWaX3EhtS0lHxAmo4RuSMH5KQh0kpswAC68wQBwFkDoNQBgyCuCjKAAAZjQOAgg1BaBiEoJAURyh3MEEgJgLyACCsgyB+DQI0fotgzmYDoGC9ApgZBGEwGgWQDBBCCDOWwHASAoB0HWKAQIwQvAJjELMM5fyMjGAiKAC5Vybl3J0IINgJhUCPOea8rQRQlCYAyDgYlIBZBsAQAYIIpgYWYDhSABFUAgjEtAEYJAILiXhBAAAYgAMLqusAAUQAELatMKqsQ2qxD9GXCAU5Sg-BkAuW81lIBmXPIpN4LFQg4APORWcxFyL7VPJeXalUShmVqCpegA4UBbX0rJfGNl-qtBZG5by-lABHBgirxXOBoKQMVsL+XStlXctQQr9DyFQOEBwqRLUgC+T831zLkA+pAHkAAfgAUlMISkIYQy0OGqjqXI-byw6krV6vQUAADWKK0UYqUFEAA8g8h5EA4A+tjRy9ARRo0gApaGyIIBkBGEnfanlfKtBMCQCYJQqgNAwDuee2QdqH7VuEGQUt2gLmYCpdG0AmAFWyAgA8+t1KQBPMEJ+lloBsUKoQFoGAbBSCXvOQgHAPK0APKCMuslxylAHqPT+pNZ6L2mGvZoe197H1nKCBYN9EaKRfpOcqX9iqANAbLaAGVggoBoucPypwmAGAIEoBkRIAA+AAvN0RIAB+RIfGBNCcSKgZIvwDjxsjDgLNbBG1cpAJ2-lCaQBkCMGwBgOAmDrBVTEU52H90XqPSAIwaL-DnMuWwa5IK7lYpxXihlchrkwrkHcvT3YlBQY8LB+DVKlCIBQ+sdDghMMBCCCEAk0K2BsDAzQHAwG-XrsEkojZOYT38sFcK9wggc0Sv5QVGokZcsBtaeEmZjiQDFa0KVkVFXuW5r2QaOYVawsIG7Xu9wngIsIYRS8uAUBV2tYI+gHAbADDIqUPV4bKobOGAvaEH1v6QhBrfQgEzy7IuIagH4Ij6AjsMBOwwT1DHTlAA)

I've tried various examples but just can't figure out how to add the z value to the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the second layer with the following code, now it works.
Hope this helps you.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAD4Y.png)

```json
    {
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "datum.y >= 0 ? datum.y : -1", "as": "y"},
        {"pivot": "c", "value": "z", "op": "values", "groupby": ["x"]},
        {
          "calculate": "datum['This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)'][0].y",
          "as": "This Month y"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum['This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)'][0].z",
          "as": "This Month z"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum['Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)'][1].y",
          "as": "Last Month y"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum['Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)'][1].z",
          "as": "Last Month z"
        }
      ],
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.3, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "This Month y",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "This Month y"
          },
          {
            "field": "Last Month y",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Last Month y"
          },
          {
            "field": "This Month z",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "This Month z"
          },
          {
            "field": "Last Month z",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Last Month z"
          }
        ]
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "hover",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "fields": ["x"],
            "nearest": true,
            "on": "mouseover",
            "clear": "mouseout"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).